# CSS border-image property not showing

Tags: html, css, border, border-image

I am having some issues with the CSS border-image property. The CSS is as follows:

```
    footer#footer {
background-image: url("http://bramcroft.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/background-footer.png");
background-color: #cccccc;
border-image: url(http://bramcroft.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/paws-border.png);
-moz-border-image: url(http://bramcroft.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/paws-border.png);
-webkit-border-image: url(http://bramcroft.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/paws-border.png);
border-image-width: 100% 0 0 0;
-moz-border-image-width: 100% 0 0 0;
-webkit-border-image-width: 100% 0 0 0;
}
```

I have an image in the footer itself, and this appears to cover the area that has been set for the border.

The website I am trying to apply this to is as follows: http://bramcroft.co.uk/

I would like the border above the brown footer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can try this by changing the desired border size

```
border:10px;
background-image: url("http://bramcroft.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/background-footer.png");
background-color: #cccccc;
border-image: url("http://bramcroft.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/paws-border.png") 30 30;
-moz-border-image: url("http://bramcroft.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/paws-border.png") 30 30;
-webkit-border-image: url("http://bramcroft.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/paws-border.png") 30 30;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Vijay, I still appear to be seeing the same issues. Perhaps it will help if I upload my website, maybe it isn't related to this CSS and rather something else. Please see the edited post at the top.

Comment: This worked when I tried it on your website. Are you sure you copied his code correctly?

Comment: Strange, I copy and pasted it first time and just tried again for my own sanity and am still receiving the same issue. Did you use the editor in a browser to test? Which browser did you use?

Comment: Just got this to work now, took a bit of fiddling as my image wasn't displaying correctly. Thanks for the help, I will mark this as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add double-quotes `"...."` to your css image path file.

Change this:

```
border-image: url(http://bramcroft.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/paws-border.png);

-moz-border-image: url(http://bramcroft.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/paws-border.png);

-webkit-border-image: url(http://bramcroft.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/paws-border.png);
```

to this:

```
border-image: url("http://bramcroft.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/paws-border.png");

-moz-border-image: url("http://bramcroft.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/paws-border.png");

-webkit-border-image: url("http://bramcroft.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/paws-border.png");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Andrew, unfortunately still having the same issue. I did wonder about the double quotes and believe I had them to begin with, however all documentation related to the property seems not to include them.